# Numbers with special factorisation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

We know that any natural number $n$ can be decomposed as $p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_n^{k_n}$. 
I am looking for numbers which have $k_1=k_2=k_3=....=k_n=1$ i.e. given a number n, identify if it has all the $k_i=1$. I am looking for fast solutions, heuristics are welcome. One can assume that primes upto $n$ are stored.

**Edit:** $p_1, p_2, ....p_n$ are any primes and not necessarily the first n primes.

Comment: This is usually referred to as $p_n$-primorial. It is written $p_n!!$ or $p_n\#.$ The numbers of this type are 2,6,30,210,... etc.

Comment: But I don't know what you mean when you say you are looking for solutions.

Comment: I presume they mean given a number $n$ test whether it is of that form.

Comment: Also, is each $p_i$ the $i$th prime number, or are they any primes? If they are in fact any primes, then numbers of the given form are called squarefree numbers.

Comment: @daniel: Please look at the edit. I am basically looking for a test for n.

Comment: hmmm....so I suppose I am looking for a test for squarefree numbers.

Comment: No one has found a way to test numbers for squarefreeness that's any faster than factoring them. See, for example, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16098/complexity-of-testing-integer-square-freeness

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *squarefree* numbers. Unfortunately, as pointed out in the comments, no test faster than factoring has been developed to determine whether a number is squarefree.